# Setting a different color to line below a certain Y value

Tags: java, android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I have created a line chart with some data using MPAndroidChart, and I now want to make the lines under a certain Y value one color, while lines above that Y value are a different color. How can I approach doing this?

For example: I want any line present under 5 to be red and any line above it to be blue.

If this is not possible, is it possible for coloring the dots?
[image]

Comment: Yes you can modify colors and all you need. But you need to write your own logic https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Custom-DataSets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the setColors() method.